# Does PayPal Checkout Express module that shipped with OpenCart 1.5.6 work for you?

Tags: paypal, opencart

I have enabled this module and I believe it is unable to send to PayPal API's any shipping price. I have tried it with Flat shipping fee and other, nothing other than the tax and price of products get sent to PayPal after pressing the PayPal express checkout button. So the address details, including the shipping cost get ditched, you can see them in checkout but they are not sent.

Can anyone please confirm if this is the case for the PayPal express checkout module that ships with 1.5.6 or maybe I am missing some config setting.

Answer (score 0):

That is because it adds the shipping when you return to your OC site - try it and you will see :)

It uses PayPal to get the address info first you see - that is the way PP Express works to speed up ordering (slightly).

Now see if you get rounding errors with PayPal where it says your cart totals do not match - if you do there is a fix to be found here - [you have to make it into a vQmod file yourself and have vQmod installed](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=113&t=51687&start=40#p434450)

If you struggle let me know and I can assist :)